# what will happen to orphaned rows in a table if I add foreign key to one of the columns

Tags: mysql, rdbms

A table in an RDBMS that has a foreign key column but was not marked as one has lead to many orphaned rows.

What will change if I Alter the table and make that column a foreign key constraint.

Table:

```
Posts: id, title, body, user_id (currently not marked as FK)
```

Will I lose the orphaned rows?

EDIT: 
1. Would it make sense to recreate the table with the correct FK constraints and port data from the old table to the new one?

Comment: You'll get an error when you try to add the constraint.

Comment: @maximl337 Per Edit question: No not really, you could just delete the orphans and then create the key, or you could create parents for each of the orphans if needed.  Deleting the child may be the wrong course of action; it depends on how the parent was removed and why.

Comment: @xQbert So I should add "mock" parent rows instead of deleting the orphaned rows before adding the FK ?

Comment: @maximl337 it depends.  Your choices are Mock up parents, delete children.  If you know that all the child records that are orphaned can safely be purged, then take that approach.  If you're Unsure, then creating a parent may be required.  Likely deleting children is appropriate, but someone who understands the data needs to make that call.  This is one of those situations where it's likely safe to delete the children, but Im cautious by nature so I want to ensure each orphan should be removed. so Id seek advice from someone who understands the data and if the records should be purged.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySQL will disallow creation of the foreign key index if it would result in "orphaned" records in the child table.

You can force creation of the index with

```
set foreign_key_checks = 0;
```

before running your `alter` query - but you will eventually have to clean up the dangling records.

Comment: So I should probably clean up the table with something like this: DELETE FROM posts where user_id not in (select id from users) and then add FK